# Darle formato a timestamp con Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, time

He intentando de muchas formas, y ninguna me sale bien. Es sencillo lo que quiero lograr hacer, no se si sea sencillo hacerlo.

Quiero transformar, esto:

```
1510060016 // time() -> PHP
```

En esto

```
Hace 1 hora
```

Mi idea era hacer algo así

```
<div time="1510060016"></div>
```

Y en Javascipt poder tomar el valor de **time** para modificarlo cada 10s con **setInterval();**

Obviamente, necesito que diga: **Hace instanstes, hace 1 hora, hace 1 día, hace 2 días, etc**

¿Qué puedo hacer?

Comment: probaste con la librería https://momentjs.com/?

Comment: La he visto en todas partes e investigue un poco y no me convenció. ¿Sabes como usarla para lograr lo que quiero hacer?

Comment: Que no te convencio? Retractate!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te dejo un ejemplo con [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/), si no quieres utilizar la excelente respuesta del colega @Asier

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.19.1/moment.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <button type="button" id="button">Obtener tiempo</button>
    
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#button").click(function(){
          alert(moment(1510060016 * 1000).fromNow());
        });
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Gracias! Una pregunta, es necesario usar si o si JQuery? Porque no utilizo JQuery

Comment: En este caso sí amigo, moment.js necesita jquery para que funcione =/

Answer (score 3):

Aquí tienes un ejemplo sin utilizar ninguna librería:

```js
function updateTimes(){
  // Seleccionamos elementos con atributo time
  var times = document.querySelectorAll('[time]');
  // Calculamos nº de segundos de la fecha actual
  var now = Math.floor((new Date()).getTime() / 1000);
  // Por cada elemento (div)
  times.forEach(function(item){
    // Calculamos la diferencia respecto a la fecha actual
    var diff = now - parseInt(item.getAttribute('time'));
    // En función del valor mostramos el dato en segundos, minutos, horas o días
    if (diff < 60){
      item.innerText = 'Hace ' + diff + ' segundos';
      return;
    }
    diff = Math.floor(diff / 60);
    if (diff < 60){
      item.innerText = 'Hace ' + diff + ' minutos';
      return;
    }
    diff = Math.floor(diff / 60);
    if (diff < 24){
      item.innerText = 'Hace ' + diff + ' horas';
      return;
    }
    diff = Math.floor(diff / 24);
    item.innerText = 'Hace ' + diff + ' días';
  });
}

updateTimes();
setInterval(updateTimes, 10000);
```

```html
<div time="1510060016"></div>
<div time="1510065371"></div>
```

Comment: creo que hace falta que luego de eso, diga en texto el tiempo que ha transcurrido segun el post dice que debe decir ha pasado X cantidad de tiempo.

Comment: ¿Y no es lo que hace el ejemplo?

Comment: a si correcto no habia visto la actualizacion saludos

Comment: ¡Gracias! ¿Me podrías explicar qué fue lo que hiciste? Si no es molestía

Comment: En `times` selecciono todos los elementos con atributo `time`. En `now` almaceno la fecha actual en segundos (lo mismo que hace php). En el `forEach` por cada elemento calculo la diferencia en segundos entre el valor del atributo `time` y `now`. Si la diferencia es menor de 60 segundos muestro el valor en segundos, si no calculo el nº de minutos. Si la diferencia es menor de 60 minutos muestro el valor en minutos, si no calculo el nº de horas. Si la diferencia es menor de 24 horas muestro el valor en horas, si no calculo el nº de días y los muestro.

Comment: Que buena respuesta, sin librerias todo es mejor !